# What tool can I use to manage a researcher network bibliography?

Tags: api, web-crawling, rdf

I am making a website for a researcher network using Jekyll and hosting it on github pages.

Each researcher (250+ people) should have his own document with an up to date bibliography.

I could request from them the bibliography in a BibTeX format and include it using Jekyll-Scholar plugin. However, it would require them to update it each time they publish a new paper.

So I looked into ResearchGate, hoping to find an API (they landed 35 Millions to make one 2 years ago). No luck, they only have a plugin system far from fulfilling my requirements.

So I wondered if there is any reliable endpoint to fetch an individual researcher bibliography, assuming she or he would agree and keep it up to date.

Comment: So in essence you're looking for some sort of feed of scientific publications that includes authors?

Comment: You could say it like that, I want a webservice where I could get back the list of publications for a specific author.

Comment: I think I should double check it but it looks like BibBase (https://bibbase.org/) is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ORCID](https://orcid.org/) provides a persistent digital identifier that distinguishes you from every other researcher and, through integration in key research workflows such as manuscript and grant submission, supports automated linkages between you and your professional activities ensuring that your work is recognized.

ORCID also has [ResearcherID integration](http://wokinfo.com/researcherid/integration/).

[ORCID.js](https://github.com/mikecrabb/ORCID.js) is a JavaScript library for doing exactly what I think you are seeking.  In the GitHub repository example, it passes an ORCID profile ID and spits out a list of the corresponding researcher's work.